# system.stdout and system.stdin is undefined in casperjs

Tags: javascript, npm, phantomjs, casperjs, commonjs

I was kind of new to casperjs more specifically javascript on native enviroments, some casperjs script has the following code fragment that gives me error on executing:

```
system.stdout.write("Old \"" + password.name + "\" password: ");
var oldPassword = system.stdin.readLine().trim();
```

I tried to install commonjs npm library but does not solved my problem, I echoed the properties of available system library as follows:

```
for(var tmp in system){
    console.log(tmp);
}
```

The out put is:

```
objectName
pid
args
env
os
isSSLSupported
destroyed(QObject*)
destroyed()
deleteLater()
_isCompletable()
_getCompletions(QString)
```

The first lines that execute the require commands as follows:

```
system = require('system');
casper = require('casper').create();
require = patchRequire(require, ['./adapters']);
config = require('./config').config;
```

And the complete source of the casperjs program I try to use is here [passup.js](https://github.com/alanctkc/passup.js#passupjs)

How can I solve this issue? I mean load system so that it has .stdout and .stdin properties. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of PhantomJS do you use?
Support for standard I/O was introduced in the 1.9 version.

Comment: @VitalySlobodin I checked that, and it turns out I was using 1.8.2. That answer was was the one that I was looking for, let me test it upgrading to 1.9. Thanks.

Comment: @VitalySlobodin, upgrading PhantomJS to version 1.9 fixed the issue, if you write your comment as answer so that I can accept your solution. Thanks.

Comment: sure. Also I'm glad that you solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of PhantomJS do you use? Support for standard I/O was introduced in the 1.9 version.

Read more here: http://phantomjs.org/release-1.9.html